# how to overwrite rows and columns in excel using HSSF

Tags: java, excel, csv, hssf, hssfworkbook

I'm trying to overwrite data in excel but it only writes last row and column while what I want is to overwrite everything.

Here is my code.

```
    for(int i=0; i < 139; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < 9; j++){
            HSSFRow read_row = worksheet.getRow(i);
            HSSFCell read_cell = read_row.getCell(j);


            if(read_cell.equals(null)){
                read_cell.setCellValue("0");                
            }       

            System.out.println("row: " + i + " cell: " + read_row.getCell(j));

            HSSFSheet worksheet1 = hwb1.getSheetAt(sheetNum);
            worksheet1.createRow(i).createCell(j);  
            HSSFRow write_row = worksheet1.getRow(i);
            HSSFCell write_cell = write_row.getCell(j); 

            write_cell.setCellValue(read_cell.getStringCellValue());             
        }

    }
```